# cannot read property get of undefined (node js)

Tags: node.js

I am new in node js . just created two files, one is app.js and another is routes.js . when i am not separating routes.js , then my code is working fine.but when i including routes.js,then giving me the "cannot read property get of undefined" error.

### app.js:

```
var express = require('express'), stylus = require('stylus'), nib = require('nib')
var app = express()

function compile(str, path) {
  return stylus(str)
    .set('filename', path)
    .use(nib());
}

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
app.set('view engine', 'jade')
app.use(express.logger('dev'))
app.use(stylus.middleware(
  { src: __dirname + '/public'  , compile: compile }
))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

var routes = require('./routes');
app.use('/', routes);

app.listen(8888)
```

### routes.js:

```
module.exports = (function() {
    'use strict';
    var router = require('express').Router();

    router.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.render('index',
       { title : 'Home' , content : 'this is testing content'}
      )
    })

    return router;
})();
```

Following is the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
at D:\m_node\routes.js:7:8
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\m_node\routes.js:14:3)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:1
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\m_node\app.js:20:14)
```

Comment: Where does that error occur? It presumably gives you some details about where the error occurred.

Comment: Hi Colin, just added the error in main issue.

Comment: There's really no need to use an IIFE in your routes.js.  A nodejs module is already scoped in its own function.

Comment: Yes the problem has been solved.Thanks eveyone